# How can i improve performance of many database inserts?

Tags: java, mysql, performance, prepared-statement

I have the following code that execute many inserts on database. Is there a way to improve performance? How?

```
public void insertMany(List<Trajectory> trajectories) {
    try {
        String sql = "insert into trajectory (id, datetime, longitude, latitude) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement insert = MySqlDriver.getInstance().getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);

        try {
            for (Trajectory trajectory : trajectories) {
                insert.setLong(1, trajectory.getId());
                insert.setTimestamp(2, Timestamp.valueOf(trajectory.getDateTime()));
                insert.setDouble(3, trajectory.getLongitude());
                insert.setDouble(4, trajectory.getLatitude());
                insert.addBatch();
            }

            insert.executeBatch();
        } finally {
            insert.close();
        } 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you wrap up your code inside a Transaction? Outside the for() loop, try finding something like `BeginTransaction` & after the loop add `EndTransaction`. It might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **useServerPrepStmts=false** and **rewriteBatchedStatements=true**

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<host Name>:<port name>/schema?useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true", "DB Username", "DB Password")
```

[image]

Comment: In my experience, 10x improvement when putting 100 row in a single INSERT statement.